# On window resize event javascript on object tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created Jquery tabs and embedded a JSP page on the parent page. I have called on window resize events on both pages. But the inner page function does not get invoked.

For the inner page I have an SVG element which needs to be resized every time the window is resized.

```
sLinkPageToJunction = '<%=base1%>' + "/InnerTabbedPage.jsp?IntersectionName=" + strIntersectionName + "&FrameName=" + strFrameName + "&ip=" + '<%=ServerIP %>' + "&port=" + '<%=ServerPORT %>' + "&InterCorridorName=" + svgfilename;
if (document.getElementById("JnLive" + strIntersectionName) == null) {
    //var nextTab = $('#tabs li').size()+1; 
    Tabcount = $('#tabs li').size();
    // create the tab
    $('<li><a href="#tab' + strIntersectionName + '" data-toggle="tab">' + strIntersectionName + '&nbsp;&nbsp; <button class="close closeTab" align="right" "type="button">x</button></a></li>').appendTo('#tabs');

    // create the tab content

    $('<div class="tab-pane" id="tab' + strIntersectionName + '"> <div id="JnLive' + strIntersectionName + '" class="col-sm-6" style="margin-top: 1%"> </div>').appendTo('.tab-content');


    var heightvalue = $(window).height();
    var widthvalue = $(window).width()

    //alert("---->"+heightvalue+"---->"+widthvalue);

    var url = "<object id=obj'" + strIntersectionName + "' data='" + sLinkPageToJunction + "' height='" + heightvalue + "' width='" + widthvalue + "'></object>";

    $("#JnLive" + strIntersectionName).html(url);

    // make the new tab active
    $('#tabs a:last').tab('show');
    OpenedTabbedJunctionNames[Tabcount - 1] = strIntersectionName;
    OpenedTabbedJunctionFrameNames[Tabcount - 1] = strFrameName;

    registerCloseEvent();
}
```

So it creates a new tab if it does not already exist.

Now my on windowresize event on the inner page is

```
window.addEventListener('resize', changeframesizeJN) ;
```

on the outer page it is

```
window.addEventListener('resize', changeframesize) ;
```

But when I resize the window with the tab selected changeframesizeJN is not invoked.

How can I do that?

P.S: I dont know if I have put the information that is required for the question to be answered. The fact is I am not sure how to ask this question.

Comment: add a http://jsfiddle.net/ to reproduce if you can (or a snippet code)

Comment: If the document inside the `<object>` element is on the same domain, you can access its documentElement from the parent window with `object.contentDocument` which would allow you to directly proceed the modifications you want to do.

Comment: @Blag, I was not in a position to reproduce a jsfiddle. I would have certainly done that if I could. Thats one of the reasons for the PS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You give your panel a fixed width and height from what I can tell from your code. You should change the CSS of your inner page to resize with it's parent.

Alternatively you could call the inner page function on the resize of its outer parent as well as its own. Since its on the same domain you won't have any problem doing this:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    changeframesize();
    window.frames['yourIframeName'].changeframesizeJN();
});
```

Just make sure you give your inner window a name so you can select it. Or use it's index but I would recommend using a name to keep it readable:

```
window.frames[0].changeframesizeJN();
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, this is exactly what I wanted. I am using frame index, though because of other constraints. Though I was not giving any width to the Panel. Its bootstrap panel. So the panel was responsive. Only thing was the SVG tag was in the inner page. So document.get was not giving me that so that I could resize the SVG.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the resize onto the object tag, like:

```
var url = "<object id=obj'" + strIntersectionName + "' onresize='changeframesizeJN()' data='" + sLinkPageToJunction + "' height='" + heightvalue + "' width='" + widthvalue + "'></object>";
```

If that works then you can bind it to the object, the same as your window, except with the object element instead.

```
objectElement.addEventListener('resize', changeframesizeJN) ;
```

Comment: Thanks, but object onresize didnt work. window.frames did the trick for me.